# Format YearMonth to dutch monthname

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following YearMonth data:

```
201601
201602
201603
```

Etcetera.

I need to convert them to dutch month names, with format 'MMM'

So 201601 should become 'jan'
201602 should become 'feb'

Etc

I have the following code:

```
SELECT FORMAT(RIGHT(YearMonth,2),'MMM', 'nl-NL') as monthname
```

I am getting this error:

```
Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function.
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what is the datatype of that column?

Comment: note that FORMAT is very slow over large datasets.  Use it with caution.

Answer (score 1):

If `YearMonth` is of type `int` then you can use following sql statement:

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(201710 / 100, 201710 % 100, 1), 'MMM', 'nl-NL')
```

and the result is: `okt`

> TODO change 201710 to `YearMonth`

## Explanation

- DATEFROMPARTS takes 3 parameters `Year`,`Month`,`Day`. The first parameter is calculated by dividing by 100: `201710 / 100 = 2017 (int / int = int)`. The second parameter is calculated using the modulo operator: `201710 % 100 = 10`

## Sample

```
CREATE TABLE #tempDates (YearMont int)

INSERT INTO #tempDates VALUES(201710)
INSERT INTO #tempDates VALUES(201711)
INSERT INTO #tempDates VALUES(201712)
INSERT INTO #tempDates VALUES(201801)

SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(YearMont / 100, YearMont % 100, 1), 'MMM', 'nl-NL') monthname FROM #tempDates
```

### Result

```
-------------
| monthname |
|-----------|
| okt       |
| nov       |
| dec       |
| jan       |
-------------
```

Answer (score 0):

If `yearmonth` is an integer, then you can convert it to a `date` first and then use `format()` like so:

```
create table t (yearmonth int)
insert into t values (201601),(201602),(201603)

select format(
    convert(date,convert(varchar(10),yearmonth*100+1))
    ,'MMM','nl-NL') as monthname
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NPPN83037

returns:

```
+-----------+
| monthname |
+-----------+
| jan       |
| feb       |
| mrt       |
+-----------+
```

---

If `yearmonth` is a character type:

```
select format(
    convert(date,yearmonth+'01')
    ,'MMM','nl-NL') as monthname
from v
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because FORMAT does not accept a string for its first parameter.  Using the RIGHT function implicitly converts the result into a string.

You can convert the output of RIGHT back into a number, but your statement would perform better if you do it with math only.  201710 % 100 will return just the remainder of 10.

Note the FORMAT command can be very slow when used across multiple rows.  You'd get better performance changing the language for the session and using other date functions such as DATENAME.